# wordpress/woocommerce infinite loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action

I am building a coupon plugin for woocommerce at the moment, one of the coupons can add a free gift to the cart, and I think I am caught in an infinite loop and I am not sure how to program myself out of it.

I am using this action,

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees',  [$this, 'c87_apply_coupon']);
```

which fires this this code,

```
public function c87_apply_coupon() {
        $coupon = $_COOKIE['c87_coupon'];
        $coupon_values = json_decode(stripslashes($coupon));
        switch($coupon_values->type) {
            case "GIFT":
               $this->c87_add_gift_to_cart();
            break;
            // case "PERCENT_ORDER_TOTAL":

            // break;
            // case "PERCENT_PRODUCTS":
               
            // break;
            case "ORDER_DISCOUNT":
            default:
                $this->c87_add_discount_to_order(75, $coupon_values);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Which in turn when the coupon type is GIFT fires this method,

```
public function c87_add_gift_to_cart() {
        if(!$this->adding)
            global $woocommerce;
            $product_id = 61778;
            $found = false;
            if(sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) {
                foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if($_product->get_id() == $product_id) {
                        $found = true;
                        $this->adding = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!$found) {
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(64148);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I assume that everytime I run the `add_to_cart` method on the cart it triggers the action and I am getting caught in an infinite loop.

Is there a way to either not fire the action for a certain product, or better yet a more intelligent way to way to write/structure my code? I have tried adding a flag($this->adding) but that has not fixed the logic.

Comment: I think you just need to also check if `64148` is in the cart already, too

Comment: The `add_to_cart` function triggers a cart update, which will then trigger `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` I think... You should re-think your idea!